# Sorting list throws KeyNotFoundException

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I've been working on an project where the application gets data from database to a list and sorts it. The problem is that for one situation the sorting needs to be done by a key that might not exist in all items.

```
// The variable list is sorted into another list called sortedList
sortedList = list.OrderBy(x => x.SomeIntegerData["key-that-is-not-in-every-item"]).ToList();
```

Some items don't have that "key-that-is-not-in-every-item" and it causes the application to throw KeyNotFoundException. I can't seem to compare it to null or something that could make the application to do something else when the key is doesn't exist.
Is there a way to use something else like a timestamp (that is quaranteed to exist in every item) to do the sorting when the key doesn't exist?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
// The variable list is sorted into another list called sortedList
sortedList = list.OrderBy(x => x.SomeIntegerData.ContainsKey("key-that-is-not-in-every-item")?x.SomeIntegerData["key-that-is-not-in-every-item"]:null).ToList();
```

Comment: This structure seems to do what I needed. Thank you!